# Loading DLL's on Java start up

Tags: java, dll, native

I was wondering if it is possible to load a DLL as you execute a java application. Maybe through some command line parameters or something like that. Basically, I just want to make sure that when Java is started, my DLL is loaded so it doesn't have to be done only when I use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [System.load(String filename)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load%28java.lang.String%29) and [System.loadLibrary(String libname)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: yeah for sure, i was just wondering if you can specify it in the command paramters

Comment: @tuck do you mean that you want in the `java [options] ...` to tell java to explicitly load a library on startup?

Comment: yeah, that is what I am referring to? Any ideas?

Comment: @tuck nope, sorry, only programatically... Umm, you could manipulate bytecode, though... If you _really_ need not to touch the code. But why can't you touch the code, anyway?

Comment: Yeah i think i might just loadlibrary it, i can touch the code, and I think it actually might be a cleaner solution now! thanks for you helps tho

Answer (score 0):

It can be one in static initializatiion block

```
public class App {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("libname");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
...
```